# Path integral through a ball with a function defined in spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, change-of-variable, path-connected

I have a function defined over the spherical coordinates $f(r,\theta,\phi)$.  A want to perform a path integral along a line parallel to the $y$-axis. Hence, the values of x and z are fixed along the path, only $y$ varies.  Let's call the fixed values of $x=x_0$ and $z=z_0$

$$\int_{y_0}^{y_1} f(r(x_0,y,z_0),\theta(x_0,y,z_0),\phi(x_0,y,z_0))dy$$

I want an expression of this integral as a function of $(r,\theta,\phi,dr,d\theta,d\phi)$ only, not of $y$ and $dy$.

I am unsure how to procede, as it is easy to integrate this over $dy$ as the function is already expressed in $y$, but to integrate this over $(r,\theta,\phi)$ is harder.  Am I supposed to take the total differential:
$$dy=\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}dr +\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}d\theta +\frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}d\phi $$

and integrate over this?  It somewhat feels wrong and I am unsure what to do.  For instance, if I were to try this, I would get a sum of $3$ integrals, with the first one being:

$$\int_{r_0}^{r_1} f(r,\theta,\phi)\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}dr$$

which doesn't seem to make much sense.  For instance, if $y_1=-y_0$, then $r_1=r_0$, so the above integral should be zero?  And how does the fact that my $x$ and $z$ coordinates are fixed  come into play when trying to do this integral?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should parameterize the path: express $(r, \theta, \phi, dr, d\theta, d\phi)$ as a function of some continuous parameter $t$, which can be evaluated under a single integral. You cannot separate the integral into $3$ separate integrals because the variables are constrained along the path.